# php function returns unexpected � (possibly unicode or bytecode caused)

Tags: php, encryption, unicode, replace, caesar-cipher

**Simple cezar cipher encryption function**

Right now, encrypting the string "g " will result in "�". Meanwhile encrypting "g" returns the expected "G". Why could be the cause of the � symbol? If the input string is "g ", the expected outcome is: "G ".

snippet of code:

```
function encrypt($plaintext, $n, $key1, $key2, $L1, $L2) {
    $result = '';
        // encrypt first half of input
    $array_key1 = preg_split('//u', $key1, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    for ($k=0; $k < (int)(mb_strlen($plaintext)/2); $k++) {
        $char = $plaintext[$k];
        if (in_array($char, $array_key1)) {
            $i = (strpos($key1, $char) + $n) % $L1;
            $result .= $key1[$i];
        } else {
           $result .= $char;
        }
    };
```

[full code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e0156498a2a55e97f386284e18fdd259dfe673b)

Comment: If `$plaintext` is multibyte then `$plaintext[$k]` might be part of a character

Comment: 1. Literally the only time you're actually treating `$plaintext` as a multibyte string is the `mb_strlen()` call, so it's probably that. 2. Why are you rolling your own encryption? 3. Don't roll your own encryption.

Comment: @sammitch too late booiii :)

Answer (score 0):

The resulting string is not properly encoded in utf-8, with is likely to be the default encoding in your php config.

the expected result shows with

```
echo utf8_encode((string)$string . "\n");
```

instead of `echo $string . "\n";`

assuming Â is the expected result of your encription.

Comment: No, I have not included the char Â in my key charset. The issue appeared when it tried to access this char: "¤" and append it to the $result var. When I printed the output, it appeared as a questionmark strangly enough. Check out the full code if you havent already. By the way I highly appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I've taken some liberties to refine/streamline your function (hope you don't mind).

Some notes:

- only pass the required data as function arguments -- let the function do the length counting and relevant processing
- by packaging `$key1` and `$key2` into a single array, your process can be make more DRY.
- by implementing `mb_` function calls in the necessary places, I *believe* this works as intended.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c0cdffdaca6bbd6fa5c25adb7a44e9f0969f45c))

```
function encrypt($plaintext, $n, $keys, $encoding='UTF-8'){

    $plain_chars = preg_split('//u', $plaintext, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $plain_halves = array_chunk($plain_chars, ceil(sizeof($plain_chars)/2));

    $result='';

    foreach($plain_halves as $i=>$chars){
        $L=mb_strlen($keys[$i]);
        foreach($chars as $char){
            echo "i = $i, char = $char, ";
            if(($offset = mb_strpos($keys[$i],$char,0,$encoding))!==false){
                echo "offset $offset & calc: ($offset+$n)%$L = ",($offset+$n)%$L," \n";
                $result .= mb_substr($keys[$i],($offset+$n)%$L,1,$encoding);
            }else{
                echo "no viable offset\n";
                $result .= $char;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "Output is: ";
    return $result;
}

$keys=[
    'aA0!bBcC"1dDeE2f#Fg¤G3%hHi&I4/jJ(kK)5l=Lm?M6@nNoO7pPqQ8rRsS9tTuUvVwWxXyYzZ',
    '1aAbBc2CdDeE3fFgG4hHjJ5kKlLm6iIwWMnNo7OpPq8QrRsS9tTuUvVxXyYzZ'
];

$string = 'g ';

var_export(encrypt($string, 1, $keys));
```

Output:

```
i = 0, char = g, offset 18 & calc: (18+1)%74 = 19 
i = 1, char =  , no viable offset
Output is: '¤ '
```

---

p.s. Here is a regex-free alternative:

```
function encrypt($plaintext, $n, $keys, $encoding='UTF-8'){
    $length=mb_strlen($plaintext);
    $key_lengths=[mb_strlen($keys[0]),mb_strlen($keys[1])];
    $midpoint=floor($length/2);
    $result='';
    for($x=0; $x<$length; ++$x){
        $i = $x<$midpoint?0:1;
        $char=mb_substr($plaintext,$x,1,$encoding);
        $result .= (($offset=mb_strpos($keys[$i],$char,0,$encoding))!==false)?mb_substr($keys[$i],($offset+$n)%$key_lengths[$i],1,$encoding):$char;
    }
    return $result;
}
```